wrap client to avoid nested function calls
I have this imaginary client:
const aFunc = async (a: number, b: number) => a + b

const client = { aFunc }

const makeClient = () => client

and here are some helper functions/types to safe invoke it
interface SuccessResult<TData> {
  success: true;
  data: TData;
}

interface ErrorResult<TError> {
  success: false;
  error: TError;
}

export type Result<TData = unknown, TError = unknown> = SuccessResult<TData> | ErrorResult<TError>;

const isSuccessResult = <TData>(result: Result<TData>): result is SuccessResult<TData> => result.success

const handleClientRequest = async <TData>(
  operationPromise: Promise<TData>,
): Promise<Result<TData, string>> => {
  try {
    const data = await operationPromise;

    return { success: true, data } satisfies Result<TData>;
  } catch (err) {
    const error = err instanceof Error ? err.message : 'Request handler error';

    return { success: false, error } satisfies Result<TData, string>;
  }
}

Now I can invoke it like this
  const result = await handleClientRequest(makeClient().aFunc(1, 2));
  if (isSuccessResult(result)) {
    console.log('Great success!');
  } else {
    console.log('Error: ' + result.error);
  }

I find the await handleClientRequest(makeClient() ungly. Is there a way to create a wrapper in order to have: const res: Result<number, string> = await wrappedClient.aFunc(1, 2);
